# Break NSString using an NSString, get everything after the string that was used to break/separate

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, substring

I'm trying to get the DOE,JOHN from the below NSString:

`IDCHK9898960101DL00300171DL1ZADOE,JOHN`

I was trying to split the string on `1ZA`, as that will be constant.

Here's what I've tried so far, but it's giving me the opposite of what I'm looking for:

```
 NSString *getTheNameOuttaHere = @"IDCHK9898960101DL00300171DL1ZADOE,JOHN";

 // scan for "1ZA"
 NSString *separatorString = @"1ZA";

 NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:getTheNameOuttaHere];

 NSString *thingsScanned;

 [aScanner scanUpToString:separatorString intoString:&thingsScanned];

 NSLog(@"container: %@", thingsScanned);
```

Output:

```
container: IDCHK9898960101DL00300171DL
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Shorter:

```
[[getTheNameOuttaHere componentsSeparatedByString:@"1ZA"] lastObject];
```

Comment: I appreciate your response! I had my blinders on when initially thinking about using componentsSeparatedByString - thinking that it could only take a string of length 1 (i.e. ",", ";", etc..) - which is not the case at all :D

Answer (score 3):

I would try using [componentsSeparatedByString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:):

```
NSArray* components = [getTheNameOuttaHere componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString];

NSString* namePart = [components lastObject];

NSLog(@"name = %@", namePart);
```

Answer (score 2):

`componentsSeparatedByString` worked great, see below:

```
NSString *name = @"IDCHK9898960101DL00300171DL1ZADOE,JOHN";

// scan for "1ZA"
NSString *separatorString = @"1ZA";

NSArray *split = [name componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString];

for (NSString *element in split) {
    NSLog(@"element: %@", element);
}
```

Output:

```
2010-04-26 16:50:58.496 [25694:a0f] element: IDCHK9898960101DL00300171DL
2010-04-26 16:50:58.497 [25694:a0f] element: DOE,JOHN
```

Comment: If someone answers correctly, you probably should add a comment to their answer with any additional details or results then mark it correct, rather than re-writing their answer and creating a new one.

Comment: uhh... i answered my own question before any additional answers were posted...check the timestamps (21:53 < 21:54)...

i marked Paul's response... i like one liners.